# Performing an integral from -infinity to infinity in Maple

Tags: math, symbolic-math, maple, integral, calculus

I'm trying to perform the following integral in Maple:

```
simplify(int(a*x^2*e^(-a*x^2), x = -infinity .. infinity))
```

But instead of returning an answer, Maple just returns back the integral statement itself:

```
int(a*x^2*e^(-a*x^2), x = -infinity .. infinity)
```

In the prettier form though (with the actual integral sign, etc). I've tried removing the "simplify()" but it doesn't make any difference.

Any idea why that is? It should return a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have just a syntax problem. The exponential function applied to x is exp(x) not e^x.

```
> int(a*x^2*exp(-a*x^2), x = -infinity .. infinity);
                /               (1/2)           \
                |             Pi                |
       piecewise|csgn(a) = 1, --------, infinity|
                |                (1/2)          |
                \             2 a               /
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth [Wolfram Alpha seems to be able to do this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28a*x%5E2*e%5E%28-a*x%5E2%29%2C+x+%3D+-infinity+..+infinity%29):

[image]

It gives an answer of `sqrt(pi) / (2 * sqrt (a))` (assuming `Re(a) > 0`).

Comment: That's definitely helpful as it confirms my previously obtained value. I wonder why Maple hates it :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell maple that `a` has positive real part. Otherwise, the integral does not exist. Consult the manual for how to do this.

IIRC, there is a `assume` function, and a `symbolic` option you can pass to various functions (including simplify and int).

Comment: Even if I declare a=1 I still get the same thing back. Why is Maple hating me?